# How can I line the texture up?

Tags: texturing

[image]

I have this brick tiles texture, but I can't make the black gap lines of this part (whatever it is called) line up with the rest of the floor. I have tried manual UV editing, scaling the UV but it doesn't work as well.

Can I somehow make it line up? I have the .blend file if needed.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Should be easy enough to just scale and move the UV island assuming the edges have been marked correctly. Share your blend file (with the texture packed into the file via File > External Data > Pack Resources) so that we can have a look. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Ok, give me a minute.

Comment: @JohnEason Ok, .blend file uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your texture perfectly aligned across the top surface and sides of the model you need to mark UV seams so that when unwrapped the top surfaces is one continuous UV island.

But first you need to clean up your model a little. There are overlapping vertices at either end of the step part of the mesh.

To get rid of those, in edit mode **select All** then open the **Merge menu** using the **M** key and choose the **By Distance** option.

Next In the **Last Operator pop-up menu** play about with the **Merge Distance** option until Blender indicates that 4 vertices have been removed.
[image]

Now we are ready to work on the UV seams.

In Edit mode, **select all**, open the **UV Mapping menu** and choose the **Clear Seam** option to remove all the existing UV seams.

Our goal is to have 2 UV islands, one for top surface and sides and the second for the underside of the model.
Start by selecting all the lower outer edges and mark them as UV seams.

Next select all for corner vertical edges and mark them as seams.

Finally select the vertical edges at either end of the step and mark them as seams . See image below :
[image]

In Edit mode with all selected hit the **U** key and choose the **Unwrap** option.
In the UV editor you should find 2 UV islands.
You will probably need to edit them a little (rotate, scale and re-position) to have the texture correctly on the model.
Because the top surfaces is one continuous UV island there will be no problem with the texture misaligned at the step.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, 3fingeredfrog! Thank you for your answer! It works well.

I have a question though. Why don't we mark seam the upper edge of this spot (Green Arrow) while we do at the (Pink Arrows)? https://gyazo.com/cbe4e8d678ac920d97e24475115179de
Do ignore the weird red arrow though. And sorry for the late reply to your answer

Comment: We don't need to mark those 2 edges as seams because they they wont cause any distortion to the mapping of the texture when UV unwrapping. Imagine you were making this model from thin cardboard, would cutting along those two edges serve any purpose?

Comment: Oh, alright then. Thank you for your answer! Very helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply scale of your wall in object mode by ctrl a -> scale, and reunwrap this face or the whole wall, and make sure it is assigned to same material as other faces. Also you may be not able to move the island in uv editing tab if the snapping is on. Idk it's really difficult to figure out the problem without seeing this

Comment: I'll try that. If you need a .blend file, I can upload it, but it won't have textures for reasons I don't understand. Thank you.

Comment: That didn't work. Well, worth a shot.

Comment: You can drop an obj file with your model, mtl file and a brick texture(s)